# Normalise string from shell command

Tags: php, string

I have the following in my PHP app:

```
$authorize = shell_exec("php acmephp.phar authorize example1.com example2.com example3.com);

var_dump($authorize);
```

The dump throws everything in a string like the one below:

```
string(2852) "Loading account key pair... Requesting an authorization token for domains example3.com, example1.com, example2.com ... The authorization tokens was successfully fetched! Solving authorization challenge for domain {"domain":"example1.com","challenge":{"domain":"example1.com","status":"valid","type":"http-01","url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/113162350386/lZ0trg","token":"Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s","payload":"Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI"}} Create a text file accessible on URL http://example1.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s containing the following content: Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI Check in your browser that the URL Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI returns the authorization token above. Solving authorization challenge for domain {"domain":"example2.com","challenge":{"domain":"example2.com","status":"valid","type":"http-01","url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/113165197506/NmqqYg","token":"qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA","payload":"qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI"}} Create a text file accessible on URL http://example2.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA containing the following content: qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI Check in your browser that the URL qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI returns the authorization token above. Solving authorization challenge for domain {"domain":"example3.com","challenge":{"domain":"example3.com","status":"valid","type":"http-01","url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/113179268136/r9ObtA","token":"4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ","payload":"4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI"}} Create a text file accessible on URL http://example3.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ containing the following content: 4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI Check in your browser that the URL 4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI returns the authorization token above. Then, you can ask to the CA to check the challenge! Call the check command to ask the server to check your URL: php acmephp.phar check -s http example1.com example2.com example3.com "
```

However, I am trying to replicate the commands from [this](https://acmephp.github.io/documentation/getting-started/2-obtain-certificate-hard.html) documentation.
The idea is to group the token and payload of each domain; and after that perform http requests.

Is there a way that I can have some sort of regular expression to extract the token and payload for each domain?

Comment: `exec` will put each line in an array if that helps.

Comment: Actually exec only prints one line, and this case it seems to print an empty string.
I just dont understand why people would down vote a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to detect the JSON parts.

```php
$string = 'Loading account key pair... Requesting an authorization token for domains example3.com, example1.com, example2.com ... The authorization tokens was successfully fetched! Solving authorization challenge for domain {"domain":"example1.com","challenge":{"domain":"example1.com","status":"valid","type":"http-01","url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/113162350386/lZ0trg","token":"Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s","payload":"Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI"}} Create a text file accessible on URL http://example1.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s containing the following content: Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI Check in your browser that the URL Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI returns the authorization token above. Solving authorization challenge for domain {"domain":"example2.com","challenge":{"domain":"example2.com","status":"valid","type":"http-01","url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/113165197506/NmqqYg","token":"qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA","payload":"qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI"}} Create a text file accessible on URL http://example2.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA containing the following content: qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI Check in your browser that the URL qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI returns the authorization token above. Solving authorization challenge for domain {"domain":"example3.com","challenge":{"domain":"example3.com","status":"valid","type":"http-01","url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/113179268136/r9ObtA","token":"4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ","payload":"4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI"}} Create a text file accessible on URL http://example3.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ containing the following content: 4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI Check in your browser that the URL 4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI returns the authorization token above. Then, you can ask to the CA to check the challenge! Call the check command to ask the server to check your URL: php acmephp.phar check -s http example1.com example2.com example3.com';
$matches = [];
$domains = [];
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}}/', $string, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $data = json_decode($match);
    $domains[$data->domain]['token']   = $data->challenge->token;
    $domains[$data->domain]['payload'] = $data->challenge->payload;
}
print_r($domains);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [example1.com] => Array
        (
            [token] => Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s
            [payload] => Ap3hSD1Lv0CMNk1UPRdskwDB-LMxSIA4l0oPg-nk_8s.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI
        )

    [example2.com] => Array
        (
            [token] => qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA
            [payload] => qBeACTjhCLWcIvlPCjODyysQdp3VfiCqAvRBUqjd6jA.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI
        )

    [example3.com] => Array
        (
            [token] => 4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ
            [payload] => 4nsTbpZ9hEpZfntupgPBiR6PmKBae_W2H8x2rThSMEQ.wEOkJloYAPvHXs7hSm6PMhg9bR1rL0IjdwgDScNj4nI
        )

)
```